# Crash and then no Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, crash, hp-pavilion

My computer crashed, which hasn't been an uncommon occurrence lately with this piece of rubbish, but this time I rebooted to find I'm missing my wireless adapter or something. Windows can't find it, I can't find it, nobody knows where it went. I tried [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1076688/708934) (several times) to no avail. I suppose I could try installing a new driver, but I have *no clue* what I'd be looking for.

In **Device Manager > Network adapters** I get

```
Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
WAN Miniport (IP)
WAN Miniport (IPv6)
WAN Miniport (L2TP)
WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
WAN Miniport (PPTP)
Wan Miniport (SSTP)
```

I'm *assuming* the only one of those I'm connecting to stuff with is the Realtek PCIe FE one, but I don't think from what I've read that it's wireless.

Can someone please tell me a) if one of these might be responsible for Wi-Fi, how do I fix it? or b) if the wireless driver pulled a Houdini, how do I get it back? Also, how likely is it the adapter just melted when my computer froze? You know, like fire and ice, except not poetic.

```
HP Pavilion 17-g121wm
SKU N9E13UA#ABA
```

Comment: I found the answers

Comment: This was a common issue on my Laptop with W10, when i was postponing W10 updates after the 3rd postpone the system just HUNG, or disable/crashed the Network so i would need to reboot, so the update finishes. Give me a few seconds ill try to search for one way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you out. First things first.

Full list of all your laptop parts : http://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx?SearchText=N9E13UA

This is the part your're missing : `Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11b/g/n 1x1 Wi-Fi adapter`

Just so you know the Replacement part no is : `792609-005`

List of all drivers for your laptop : https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-17-g100-notebook-pc-series/8499304/model/8961418

1. Lets download the Wifi Driver : http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp73001-73500/sp73310.exe
2. Then we launch as "Runas As Administrator" the `sp73310.exe`

2.1 if the the SETUP does not launch after extracting please follow step 3, else skip to 4.

3. Most of time HP installers launch automatically after extracting but to be on the safe side move to `c:\SWSetup\SP73310` there you will find `SETUP.EXE` launch as Admin.
4. Then press `Next, Next , Next..... Finish -> Reboot Laptop`
5. Now please check if WIFI works
6. Check also if you by accident have `Turned ON Flight mode` disable by pressing FN+F10 or F11 or the one F button with the little plane on it.

Please tell me what happens so i can update accordingly.

Comment: I downloaded the driver and ran it, then went to step 3 when it didn't do anything. It gave me the "preparing InstallShield Wizard" dialog then when it finished nothing happened again. I tried several times, it just closes after the initial dialog. Yes, as admin. Also @6: Airplane mode isn't on and Windows explicitly tells me it can't find the wireless adapter.

Comment: First, using Device Manager, uninstall any existing driver before (re)installing the one downloaded. Second, if this still does not work, check if the issue is the adapter itself: download a Linux distro such as Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, create a bootable USB flash drive, and see if WiFi works in Linux, running from the USB stick. [You might even find Linux more stable than Windows for your PC.]